# Turn off emoticons on OSX

Tags: macos, mac, ios

I'd like to disable emoticons showing automatically as pictures on my laptop. I'd like it so that, for example, a colon followed by a right bracket [ :) ] shows as those characters rather than as a smiley face.

Anyone have any more thoughts on this?

Comment: Questions about iPhone are off-topic here.  I edited that part out of your question.

Comment: OK, where would I ask iPhone questions?

Comment: You can ask at https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I've never known OS X to auto-replace text with emoticons; unless this is something new with Sierra [which I'm staying well clear of for now]. Is it doing it to this :) or this :-) ?

Comment: It's not new for Sierra, it's been there at least the previous two versions as well. I've only noticed it in Mail, Messages and Chrome, but I suppose those are the places people most frequently use emoticons.

Comment: And I'm not sure if it's :) or :-), I can't actually work out how to make it show the underlying characters at all. It's like once it's been decided it's a picture, it doesn't want to show it as anything but.

Comment: I don't care what the underlying chararacters are, I just want to not have emoji on my desktop operating system. (10.12.6)